# How can I initialize "for row in file" loop?

Tags: python

I'm struggling with python's "for" initialization problem.
I'd like to detect lacks of numbers in a text file, example:

```
1001 :foo foo
1002 :foo foo
1004 :foo foo
1006 :foo foo
1007 :foo foo
1008 :foo foo
```

From this file, lacks of 1003 and 1005 should be detected.
And here's my code:

```
import sys
import os

args = sys.argv
if (len(args) < 4):
    print("Invalid args")

path = args[1]
numstart = int(args[2])
numend = int(args[3])

with open(path, mode='r') as f:
    for numfind in range( numstart, numend ):
        for row in f:
            flag = row.find(str(numfind))
            if (flag != -1):
                print("found: " + str(numfind))
                break
        else:
            print("Not found: " + str(numfind))
```

I expected to scan `f` from first row every loop of `for row in f`
but I got like this:

```
Found: 1001
Found: 1002
Not found: 1003
Not found: 1004
Not found: 1005
Not found: 1006
Not found: 1007
Not found: 1008
```

And I think there's no iteration of `for rows in f` loop.
This works:

```
for numfind in range( numstart, numend ):
    with open(path, mode='r') as f:
        for row in f:
            flag = row.find(str(numfind))
            if (flag != -1):
                print("found: " + str(numfind))
                break
        else:
            print("Not found: " + str(numfind))
```

Yes it works, but this hack is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You open the file `f` and then iterate over it (reading it), without resetting the file to the initial position between `for` loops with `f.seek(0)`. After the first `for row in f`, `f` will have no more rows to read, so it essentially becomes a no op (and why you see no iteration). You want:

```
with open(path, mode='r') as f:
    for numfind in range( numstart, numend ):
        for row in f:
            flag = row.find(str(numfind))
            if (flag != -1):
                print("found: " + str(numfind))
                break
        else:
            print("Not found: " + str(numfind))
        f.seek(0)
```

The reason your second approach works by opening the file within the loop is that you are re-reading the file from the first line every loop, which is what we achieve by adding the `f.seek(0)` above.

Comment: Another option is to read the file into a list once, then loop through the list.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
counter = numstart

with open(path, mode='r') as f:
    for row in f:
        if count == numend:
            break
        if str(counter) not in row:
            print('Not found: ' + str(counter))
        counter += 1
```

Even simpler:

```
with open(path, mode='r') as f:
    not_found = [n for line, n in zip(f, range(numstart, numend)) if str(n) not in line]

print(not_found)
```

Comment: Thank you. And I apologize you that I should search from more complicated file (must contain tabs and some dizziness). but this solution is great idea and helped me lot, I think. Thanks again!